# DateFormat error in android

Tags: android, android-framework

I'm using `DateFormat.format("EEEE d MMMM", new Date())` ,for arabic it displaying as :
الثلاثاء 29 ٥

can anyone tell me how can i get that 29 in the specific locale(which was set) numeral or least how can i ignore the current locale set and display date in English only for all locales.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239937/custom-date-format-in-android-for-given-locale) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android) I believe you will find it very inspiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get the date in required format whatever the locale may be,the code goes as:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM",new Locale("en"));
textViewID.setText(sf.format(new Date()).toString());
```

This will display date as

> **Wednesday 29 August**

dont forget to add

`import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

Answer (score -1):

Check  whether your `Locale` is supported in Android or not executing the following code.

```
   for (Locale locale:Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        Log.d(locale.getDisplayCountry(),locale.toString()); 
    }
```

Comment: No no ...nothing to do with support cause its displaying 29 for all the locales